# How do I add a column to a csv file based on another csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Let's say I have two CSV files that have an ID field with some information. I want to add the information from file one onto file two (by creating a third file) by comparing the ID information.

```
File 1:
ID   Age   Food
A-1   15   Chips
B-2   26   Donuts
C-3   8    Candy
D-4   35   None

File 2:
ID   Name
C-3  Cindy    
D-4  Bob
B-2  Dunkey
A-1  Chris
```

I would like the output to place the name column in between the Age and Id column of File 1 in relevance the ID. I know this is asking a lot but any help would be greatly appreciated. Ideal output:

```
File 3:
ID    Name    Age   Food
A-1   Chris    15   Chips
B-2   Dunkey   26   Donuts
C-3   Cindy    8    Candy
D-4   Bob      35   None
```

Even if the ID is out of order like in file 2, the output wouldn't change.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are looking is called join, and in pandas can be achieved with the function `.merge()`. In your case, you should join both dataframes on column `ID`.

```
file_1 = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Location_of_file_1.csv')
file_2 = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Location_of_file_2.csv')
```

Once you have read your files, you can join them with the following syntax:

```
file_3 = file_1.merge(file_2,how='left',on='ID')
```

Comment: I am getting this [error](https://imgur.com/4kAZGxe)